# Evernote API show all note in a notebook

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach, evernote

I'm trying to get all of the notes from a particular evernote notebook. I am able to display all of the data as an array, and I'm trying to use a foreach loop to get the title. I also want to be able to get the content, date, etc.

```
$filter = new NoteFilter();
$filter->notebookGuid = $notebookGuid;
$notelist = $client->getNoteStore()->findNotes($authToken, $filter, 0, 100);

foreach($notelist as $value) {
    echo $value->title;
}
```

I know that I'm being really stupid, but I'm new to php and evernote. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of [NoteStore.findNotes](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotes) is [NoteList](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NoteList) which is not a collection. You have to get `notes` attribute from NoteList and then iterate it.

By the way, [findNotes](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotes) is now deprecated so please use [findNotesMetadata](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotesMetadata).

Comment: My code now looks like this:

$notebookGuid = "xxxxxx";

$filter = new NoteFilter();
$filter->notebookGuid = $notebookGuid;
$notes = $noteStore->findNotes($authToken, $filter, 0, 100);

foreach ($notes as $note) {
    echo $note->title;
}

But I keep getting a warning that says "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: You have to get `notes` attribute from the return value so if you do  `$notes = $noteStore->findNotes($authToken, $filter, 0, 100);`, the collection of notes is `$notes->notes`. `$notes` itself is not a collection you can iterate. See the structure of NoteList: http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NoteList

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the following example from evernote:

https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-php/blob/master/sample/client/EDAMTest.php